# End To End Testing on Headless Server

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, headless, digital-ocean, end-to-end

I am trying to set up an environment for **end-to-end** testing on a droplet running Ubuntu server 12.04.3 on digital ocean.

What I am trying to achieve in the end is for my **jenkins** (installed on the one droplet) to be able to run my end-to-end tests. Now, the server is ofcourse **headless** and the end-to-end tests need to run through a browser (I am using protractor with the selenium standalone server with chromedriver).

My question is: **how do I spawn a browser on that machine**? **I have installed xorg** and if I do `startx` on the server, log out and `ssh -X` to it, I can manually run the end-to-end tests (a browser pops up on my local machine). But I can get it to work without `ssh -X` to it, and since jenkins is on the same droplet where the tests are to be run. Well I dont get a browser to spawn.

NOTE: I know I might be missing something really trivial here since I don't fully understand the configuration nor the xorg.

Any hints or a complete answer is very much appreciated, this is giving me gray hair.

Edit: After a little digging I think i got the xorg stuff a bit wrong, i am guessing the purpose of X is to be able to spawn a window on a remote machine ( ie my local machine). And what i am after is more along the lines of a virtual frame buffer such as Xvfb...

Comment: I'm looking to do something very similar with Jenkins. If you end up finding out any tips, I'd love to hear about them.

Answer (score 7):

There is PhantomJS but with Protractor is [buggy and a dead-end](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/ec985d2a355aa55f398c018aa5392ea296f07486/docs/browser-setup.md#setting-up-phantomjs).

You can still use Chrome & Firefox headless through [docker-selenium](https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium) or, if you don't like [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) you can do it yourself with [ubuntu-headless](https://github.com/elgalu/ubuntu-headless) sample. Both solutions provide Chrome & Firefox by using [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) even though there is no real DISPLAY.

**UPDATE 2** Seems to be possible to run Xvfb in OSX: http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/

**UPDATE 1** Mac OSX selenium headless solution:

#### Enable multi-user remote desktop access to OSX machine

So can test selenium headless on mac. Not headless really but as another user so it doesn't interfere with your current user display.
To do this you need kickstart: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201710
Begin using the kickstart utility

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -restart -agent
```

Activate Remote Desktop Sharing, enable access privileges for all users and restart ARD Agent:

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -restart -agent -privs -all
```

Apple Remote Desktop 3.2 or later only

Allow access for all users and give all users full access

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -configure -allowAccessFor -allUsers -privs -all
```

Kickstart help command

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -help
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of angular apps use [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) to perform Protractor based end-to-end integration tests on headless vms all the time.  I do not know the details of exactly how they do it but I do  know that they use a linux service called [xvfb](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) which is a headless x windows implementation.  Looking at a typical Travis configuration file, it appears that all they do before firing up their web server, selenium server and kicking off Protractor is to call `sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start` to start this service.