# Protractor brings window to foreground when taking screenshot

Tags: webdriver, screenshot, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Protractor / webdriver seems to be bringing the window to foreground every time you take a screenshot programmatically from a test spec:

```
browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
   // code that stores screenshot to hard-drive
});
```

Is there any way how to control this behaviour? I would ideally like to keep it in the background when running tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no workaround selenium side.

The option is a headless solution so e2e doesn't interrupt you while running the tests, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23461432/511069

I use [ubuntu-headless](https://github.com/elgalu/ubuntu-headless) solution for this, you can still see the browser through a VNC connection but focus doesn't affect you ever.