# Is it possible to run protractor test with the head on a remote browser?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

Can we run the test on our server and display the progress using the users browser ,So our servers have no graphics drivers, we run headless.
Is it possible to run with the head on a remote browser ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is PhantomJS but with Protractor is [buggy and a dead-end](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/ec985d2a355aa55f398c018aa5392ea296f07486/docs/browser-setup.md#setting-up-phantomjs).

You can still use Chrome & Firefox headless through [docker-selenium](https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium) or, if you don't like [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) you can do it yourself with [ubuntu-headless](https://github.com/elgalu/ubuntu-headless) sample. Both solutions provide Chrome & Firefox by using [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) even though there is no real DISPLAY.

You can also use selenium in the cloud through a paid service like SauceLabs or BrowserStack.

In OSX and without docker you can try  http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/

In OSX and without docker you can also try [Mac OSX selenium headless solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23461432/511069)

Comment: Hi @Leo , can I use Chrome and Firefox even if Selenium RemoteWebDrive is not installed on the remote machine ?

Comment: In the option docker-selenium Chrome&Firefox are installed inside the container.

Comment: In ubuntu-headless you install them by following the instructions there.

Comment: In SauceLabs or BrowserStack they install the browsers in their servers for you, that's what you pay for among other things.